# Statusbar overlap bagde label in navigationbar when push navigation iOS 11

Tags: statusbar, ios11, navigationbar, badge

In iOS 10, it looks OK but in iOS 11, the statusbar overlap badge label when push navigation. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Please see my image:

[image]

Comment: a little code would be helpful

Comment: am also facing the same issue? Did u find the solution?